# Why is it said transformers are more parallelizable than RNN's?

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, transformer, batch-size

The parallelization of transformers and RNNs (Recurrent Neural Networks) is often discussed. It's commonly said that transformers are more parallelizable than RNNs. However, this is a rather vague statement that merits further discussion.

One could argue that an RNN can be made as parallelizable as desired by simply adding more instances to each batch.

What is generally meant by saying transformers are more parallelizable is that transformers lack time-dependent operations. In other words, given an input, all operations can be done at once (although not all, since one layer needs to be computed before the next).

Contrast this with an RNN, where computations from one time step are carried forward and used in the next. Some people argue that this time-dependence makes RNNs less parallelizable.

However, one could also argue that to achieve a level of parallelization in an RNN similar to that in a transformer, one could simply increase the batch size by a factor equal to the number of time steps in the sequence. This way, both the transformer and the RNN would perform the same training in the same time frame.

A potential counterpoint to this argument might be that this would increase the memory requirements for the RNN, as the entire unfolding of the network needs to be stored. However, the memory requirement for an RNN grows linearly with the size of the input, whereas for a transformer, it grows quadratically.

Therefore, one could argue that, given their linear memory growth, RNNs should actually require less memory than transformers, making them just as parallelizable.

I look forward to getting some clarity on this issue. Does the parallelization advantage of transformers over RNNs lie in something more than just memory and time-step computations?

I understand there might be other reasons why to choose a transformer over a RNN, for instance the vanishing gradient problem, but I'm particularly interested in the statement "Transformers are more parallelizable than RNN's" because it doesn't seem obvious to me why this would be true.

There might also be good reasons for not wanting to increase the batch size, I'm interested on that too.